# Parent controller can see properties set in child controller when I expected undefined

Tags: angularjs, scope

I have the following Angular code:

index.html

```
<body>
    <main ng-app="app">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="parent" ng-controller="ParentController">
                <p>{{person.name}}</p>
                <p>{{person.email}}</p>
                <div class="child" ng-controller="ChildController">
                    <div class="">
                        <p><input type="text" ng-model="email"></p>
                        <button ng-click="updateEmail(email)" name="button">Submit Email</button>
                    </div>
                    <p>{{person.name}}</p>
                    <p>{{person.email}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>

    <script src="scripts\lib\angular.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="scripts\controllers\ParentController.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>
```

and app.js

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("ParentController", ParentController);
app.controller("ChildController", ChildController);

ParentController.$inject = ["$scope"];
ChildController.$inject = ["$scope"];

function ParentController($scope) {
    $scope.person = {
        name: "Name"
};
}

function ChildController($scope) {
    $scope.person.email = "Not the real email";
    $scope.updateEmail = function(theEmail) {
        $scope.person.email = theEmail;
    };
}
```

I expected to see "undefined" dipslayed on the page for the {{person.email}} that's inside ParentController and outside ChildController, but this isn't what happened. When the page is loaded, I can see my placeholder value in both the ParentController and ChildController. If the property hasn't been set on the object yet, how can ParentController see the value of that's set in the ChildController. I know ChildController should be able to see everything in ParentController because of inheritance, which is exactly what I was testing out. But why can ParentController see the value of person.email?

Comment: the reason is, when `ChildController` takes `person` object, that time it take reference of `ParentController` object rather than creating a new(per Prototypal inheritance)

Comment: So the reference is done automatically like that? I didn't think anything would change until ChildController was manually updated.

Comment: I'd highly recommend to read up on [Understanding of scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes)

Comment: It's just that I thought ParentController would be rendered before ChildController set the person.email property, so I would see undefined until I changed ChildController manually.

Comment: look into `controller as` syntax also, it will help organize your scopes better.